# Programmatically disable "trap unhandled exceptions" mode in winpdb

Tags: python, debugging, winpdb

I am using [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) to debug a python script. I would like to turn off the "trap unhandled exceptions" mode by default. Manually attaching the winpdb debugger and clicking the lightning button on every restart is too much work.

Ideally I would do something like this at the beginning of my script

> import rpdb2;
>     rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('password', timeout=0, trap_unhandled=False)

But unfortunately the trap_unhandled argument doesn't exist.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import rpdb2; rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('mypassword')
rpdb2.g_debugger.set_trap_unhandled_exceptions(False)
```